# Keras getting wrong output shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

For the following CNN

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(3, 256, 256)))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 64, 256, 256)

# add a 3x3 convolution on top, with 32 output filters:
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 32, 256, 256)
print(model.summary())
```

However model summary gives the following output

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
convolution2d_44 (Convolution2D) (None, 3, 256, 64)    147520      convolution2d_input_24[0][0]     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_45 (Convolution2D) (None, 3, 256, 32)    18464       convolution2d_44[0][0]           
====================================================================================================
Total params: 165984
```

Why am i getting the given output shape ?

Comment: This may sound trivial but I spent an hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. To future me, turns out I fed the wrong outputs to the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a problem caused by the setting of `input_shape`. In your current setting, you want to input 256x256 with 3 channels. However, Keras thinks you are giving 3x256 image with 256 channels. There several ways to correct it.

- Option 1: Change the order in `input_shape`
- Option 2: Specify `image_dim_ordering` in your layers
- Option 3: Modify the keras configuration file by changing 'tf' to 'th' in your ~/.keras/keras.json

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful.

Comment: in ~/.keras/keras.json, change "image_dim_ordering": "tf" to "image_dim_ordering": "th"

Comment: Where does the [None, ... extra dimension come from?

Comment: @Yakku - I raised a question separate. Would appreciate your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955044/keras-output-shape-has-an-extra-dimension