# Keras output shape has an extra dimension

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a neural network that takes in an RGB colour image of 500px by 500px and will also output another image of the same dimensions.

Here's the structure of my network:

```py
Generative_Model = Sequential([ 

   Conv2D(32, (6, 6), padding="same", name="generative", input_shape=(500,500, 3), data_format="channels_last")  

   PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros'), 

   Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding="same"), 
   PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros', name="outp1"), 

])
```

The problem I'm having is that the dimensions coming out are [None, 500, 500, 3]
though I was expecting them to be [500, 500, 3]. I'm not sure where the extra dimension is coming from.

It's important that the dimensions are removed before leaving the Network as this feeds into a second adversarial network.

Here's what I get when I print `model.summary()`:

[image: output from model.summary()]

I've tried adding a reshape at the end to force the network to drop the last dimension but it doesn't appear to be working as the output shape appears to remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst speaking to @Dodge in chat he pointed me to the following docs:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape

which states that the additional None comes from the batch length. I needed to feed the output of the first network into the output of a second which expected not to have the batch dimension so I removed this using a reshape outside of the first network like so:

```py
#Adversierial network which is comprised of a generator network and a discriminator network.
self.model = Sequential([
   Gen_Input, # Generator Network
   Reshape((500, 500, 3), input_shape=(500, 500, 3)),
   discriminative_model.Input # Discriminator Network
        ])
```

This allowed me to reshape the output from inside the graph.

Comment: This likely will not work. If the input of the discriminator network is 3-dimensional, you will feed data of the shape `(batch_dimension, 500, 500, 3)` (think of a list `[image, image, image]` where each image is `500*500*3`). Just attach the output to the input.

Comment: @IonicSolutions thank you  for your input, at the moment I'm sending through one image at a time. I'm going to extend it later to take in batches of images. This is because I'm learning the ropes at the moment so want to tackle things a step at a time; but you're right. you'll need to factor in the batch dimension if you're processing batches of images.